# Undefined symbol: type metadata accessor for EthereumKit.Wallet error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a framework using Swift. After i import [EthereumKit](https://github.com/yuzushioh/EthereumKit) in my framework to be used, i am met with the error

Undefined symbol: type metadata accessor for EthereumKit.Wallet

the picture for the error is as: 
[image]

I checked my framework search path and i also tried to enter `$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift/$(PLATFORM_NAME)` in my library search path but it didnt work. Anyone knows how we are able to solve this error?